# Move Chrome Window Buttons to Left

Tags: xfce, chrome, xubuntu

I am on Xubuntu 17.04 and I would like to have window buttons on the left without having to turn on native window decorations. The following used to work for me in Gnome in a previous installaton.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string close,minimize,maximize:
```

But this doesn't work anymore.

I am using Chrome 59 at the moment. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in both elementaryOS & Ubuntu GNOME. It is a recurrent issue that I faced in several versions of Chrome / Chromium. Last time it was broken was few months ago with version 53/54, and got fixed in 55, however the new release 59 uses GTK styling and doesn't listen to old settings so it's broken again :/ Here is a relevant thread on the Chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21438